# Chrome crash when i try to download a file from a url in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, crash

so i'm trying to use chrome extension to download a file from url.
to do that i pass with the runtime.sendmessage() a url and then the listener in my background.js try to make some magic.
Message arrives correctly and i can reply with sendResponse() without errors.
When i try to add my function that use chrome.downloads.download() inside the listener function to make the user download the file, the chrome app crash. I don't know how to check if i have some error cause it close everything..

background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        let url = request.url; //request correctly arrive

        let filename = url.split("/");
        filename = filename[filename.length - 1]; //just a split to get the name of the file from the url where i have to point
        try{
            download(url, filename);//If i don't call the chrome.download nothing crashes, 
                                    //viceversa if i only call the chrome.download and not the onMessage, it doesn't crashes
                                    //it crashes only when i combine the listener and the download method
        }
        catch(exception){
            sendResponse({status: "KO", message: "Download not completed: " + exception, url:url, filename:filename}); 
        }

        sendResponse({status: "OK", message: "Download completed", url:url, filename:filename}); 
        return true;
    })


function download(url, filename) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: url,
        filename: "videos/" + filename //Create a video folder inside default download folder
    })
}
```

manifest.js

```
{
    "name": "Camnet",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage","downloads"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
      ]
}
```

contentScript.js

```
document.getElementById('generaVideo').addEventListener("click", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ url: "http://mirrors.prometeus.net/centos/8.3.2011/isos/x86_64/CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-boot.iso" }, function (response) {
        console.log(response.message);
        alert(response.url);
        alert(response.filename);
    });
}, false)
```

the download is just a centos distro.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well, I tried it both w/ manifest version 2 and 3. I think it might be a chrome bug.

Comment: It's crashing when I just do `chrome.downloads.download({url: "http://mirrors.prometeus.net/centos/8.3.2011/isos/x86_64/CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-boot.iso"})` ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running with manifest 3, but then I converted it to manifest 2 with:

```json
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
}
```

I have no idea why it is failing as service_worker or how to make it run as persistent. I mean, isn't it already persistent as a service_worker?